# First chinese char automatically moves to end of string after double space

Tags: delphi, internationalization, delphi-xe2, translation, chinese-locale

At the moment I'm translating the software to chinese. I have a problem with the input of chinese characters (the symbols).

When I add chinese words, the first character moves to the end of the string.

### Example words:

- wo yao guilin | Chinese (我要桂林)
- wo yao guilin   ----------> (要桂林我 ) // the first character moved to the end.

When I write in chinese, pressing the space key merges the previous chinese character with the new one. The problem is, when I press space bar again the first character moves to the end of the string!

I have already changed the `IMEMode`, the project properties, the windows language, windows input method, windows locale, but nothing did solve this problem!

I have tested in portuguese, spanish, english and chinese. This problem only occurs with chinese.

I don't understand chinese at all, but a chinese said to me that this behavior is wrong.

### Additional information

- notepad.exe, the character doesn't change the position.
- I Created new project (for tests) and the problem doesn't happened.
- The problem happen in the Chrome component. It is interfering in software behavior.

Comment: The version is: Delphi XE2.

Comment: I'm inputting the text usign the "Pinying New Experience" with Chinese Simplified（PRC). The component is TEdit. thanks

Comment: Some chinese is written LTR and some RTL, could there be a conflict here?

Comment: Maybe yes, but why does it moves only the first character to the last? And it doesn't invert all the string?

For example notepad.exe, the character doesn't change the position.

Comment: Is it TEdit, or is it Chromium?

Comment: The problem happen in TEdit, because i'm using TChromiun. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved my problem!

TChromium was disturbing the input chinese characters in TEdit component. I Remove the component and the application is fine again.

Thanks for help.